# Is it better to dispose off property now or wait for its inheritance for selling ?

Tags: india, capital-gains-tax

My mother-in-law owns a flat in Mumbai and she is not currently staying there.

What is less troublesome and less taxable out of these two :

1. Selling the flat while she is alive
2. Selling it after their daughters inherit it

What are the tax liabilities for her if she sells it now or tax liability after her daughters sell it after inheritance ?

Answer (score 2):

Tax wise both options are same. On sale of property [when mother-in-law] is alive or after inherited, capital gains tax is applicable. If it is held for more than 3 years from the time when your mother-in-law purchased the property, one has to find the cost of acquisition and cost of sale. The difference is treated as long term capital gains. This is currently at 10% without indexation and 20% with indexation. You can choose either method to determine the taxes.

If you sell while your mother-in-law is still alive, it would be more easier. If you are selling after it is inherited, there needs to be a will, and property needs to be transferred/registered to new owners before a sale can be made.

Comment: Also keep in mind that after the inheritance, all the new owners need to agree to every detail of the sale. When one of them is uncooperative it can get really messy. Not just financially but also for your family life. I have seen various families break apart over an inherited real estate property.